# Break apart a string by character position

Tags: java

Suppose I have a number that was entered by a user

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Input a number.");

String num = input.next();
```

num must have a length of 50, which is implemented by a boolean method.

How can I create a new string that takes only the first 45 digits of the num?

Example entered string "123456789"

Needed only the first 5 numbers of String num "12345"

Could I convert the string to an int and use modulus?

Comment: I think you want String.substring(), but it is a little difficult to tell for sure from your question...

Comment: What part of the question don't you understand? I will certainly clean it up if you point out the gray areas.

Answer (score 2):

```
try
{
   String substr = num.subString(0,45) ;
}
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException exception)
{

   System.out.println(exception) ;

}
```

To explain: `subString(index, length)`

index is the position you want to start the operation and length the amount of string you want. 
If length specified is greater than length of string, you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, which I catch in the try catch block

Answer (score 2):

use string.substring() metod from java API.

String output = num.subString(0,45) ;